# Modify combination of LaTeX-generated indices into a useful data frame

Tags: r, regex, latex, knitr

Several of my documents output as PDFs through RStudio, `.Rnw` scripts, `knitr` and `LaTeX` have lengthy indices.  `readLines`can read into `R` each document's index (a "file.ind" file) and I have combined them all into a single character vector.

The vector looks like below, but the PDF document indents the \subitem terms (which I call 'Secondary' terms) under the \item term (which I call 'Primary' terms).  The combined vector has more than 20 Primary terms (such as **Data** and **Statistics**) and 2,000 Secondary terms (such as 'distribution, bell curve, normal, 20). A Primary term can have from 5 to 50+ Secondary terms.

```
\item Data
\subitem distribution, bell curve, normal, 20
\subitem absolute number, 111
\subitem arithmetic mean, 21
\subitem big data, 137
\subitem binary, 110
\subitem categorical, 130
\item Statistics
\subitem count, 53
\subitem data, 53, 129
\subitem data, missing, 135
\subitem digits, 53
```

The programming challenge is to "fill in" the Primary term until the next Primary term begins, and then fill in that second Primary term until the next one begins, and so on.  Or, how can `R` create an object that looks something like this with two columns?

```
Primary Secondary
Data    distribution, bell curve, normal, 20
Data    absolute number, 111
Data    arithmetic mean, 21
Data    big data, 137
Data    binary, 110
Data    categorical, 130
Statistics  count, 53
Statistics  data, 53, 129
Statistics  data, missing, 135
Statistics  digits, 53
```

My goal is to save the modified, combined indices in Excel so that I can more easily standardize the naming conventions, detect missing terms, fix misspellings, and more.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like the following should work (untested fully, but most pieces tested).  You can read your input file line by line, and then handle two types of input:

- the line starts with `\item`

  - in this case, record the new primary label, but *don't* actually write anything to the data frame
- the line starts with `\subitem`

  - in this case, write a row to the data frame using the latest primary and the secondary from the current line

```
df <- data.frame(Primary=character(),
                 Secondary=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

# replace 'filepath' with the actual path to your file
con = file(filepath, "r")
primary <- NA
secondary <- NA
while (TRUE) {
    line <- readLines(con, n=1)
    if (length(line) == 0) {
        break
    }
    if (substr(line, 2, 5) == 'item') {
        primary <- gsub("\\\\item\\s+(.*)", "\\1", line)
    }
    else if (substr(line, 2, 8) == 'subitem') {
        secondary <- gsub("\\\\subitem\\s+(.*)", "\\1", line)
        df$Primary <- primary
        df$Secondary <- secondary
    }
    else {
        print(paste0("Unexpected input: ", line))
    }
}
close(con)
```

Note that if you don't know what the actual path to your file is, then just look up the file in Windows explorer and copy the path out.  On Linux you would grep for the file, or find its location and type `pwd`.

**Update:**

Based on your comments, it sounds like maybe the data you showed us is already inside a character vector.  You can simplify what I had above to the following:

```
primary <- NA
secondary <- NA
for (i in 1:length(IndxAll)) {
    line <- IndxAll[i]
    if (length(line) == 0) {
        break
    }
    if (substr(line, 2, 5) == 'item') {
        primary <- gsub("\\\\item\\s+(.*)", "\\1", line)
    }
    else if (substr(line, 2, 8) == 'subitem') {
        secondary <- gsub("\\\\subitem\\s+(.*)", "\\1", line)
        df$Primary <- primary
        df$Secondary <- secondary
    }
    else {
        print(paste0("Unexpected input: ", line))
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need some guidance on your code.  If my file with all the combined indices (looking like the first bit of data I included in the question) is called 'IndxAll', why do I need to use file() and readLines() again?

Comment: I have answered your question with what I think is a concise and correct solution.  If you don't like it you can wait for other answers or just try yourself.

Comment: Your coding abilities are far beyond mine.  I am sure the answer is concise and correct, but a little exegesis would greatly help me and other readers to be able to implement it.  My comment was only to try to understand what you have so skillfully written.  I only got this far.  con = file(filepath, "r")
Error in file(filepath, "r") : object 'filepath' not found

Comment: @lawyeR On Windows just use the absolute path to your file, e.g. `C:\\users\\lawyer\\input.txt` ... Other than this, the rest of my script should be pump and dump.

Comment: I see; you have started with the .ind files (there are currently 10).  I have already read them in and cleaned them so that what I reproduced in the question is the current format.  You based your substr() lines on that but it is very different in the original .ind files.  How can I use my R object as the starting point and then your code pertaining to the two bullet points?

Comment: Are you saying that what you showed me is a 1D character vector?  Yeah, that simplifies things...there is probably a 1 or 2 line solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152385/discussion-between-lawyer-and-tim-biegeleisen).